# Inverse image of function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Let $f:A\to B$ be a function such that

$A= \{1,2,3\}, B=\{1,2,3\}$

$f(1)=1 , f(2)=1, f(3)=2$

Then is the inverse image of $f^{-1}(B) = \{1,2,3\}$?

And, $f^{-1}(1) = \{1, 2\}$ but is it okay because it is not a function?

and then the inverse image of the (well-defined)function is always domain of $f$?

I'm confused...

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Oh sorry... I read it and I tried my best on my question but... It seems it was not enough. I'll do better next time...

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is no.
Since $f$ is not one-to-one, the inverse of $f$ does not exist.

However for your second question is yes.
Since for a function, every object will have an image. So the pre-image of $B$ under function $f$,denoted by $f^{-1}(B)$ is always equal to $A$.

Comment: Then, if a function is homomorphism, then we may not be sure that whether it has the inverse of image or not, right??

Comment: i think this is not related to homomorphism. A relation between two set $A$ and $B$ is said to be a function if $\forall a\in A, f(a)\in B$ and if $a_1=a_2$ then $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ where $a_1,a_2\in A$. So by the first property of function we can guarantee that every element of $B$ must have a pre-image in $A$.

Comment: I actually uploaded this question because I didn't understand this:
Let $f : G \to G'$be a group homomorphism, and let H= Ker(f). Let $a \in G$ .  Then the set $f^-1 [{f(a)}]$ ={$x \in G$ | $f(x) = f(a)$}

Is $f^-1$ valid in this sentence??

Comment: Is $f^-1$ means it already  one- to one?

Comment: @JAEMTO The $f^{-1}\{f(a)\}$ refers to the pre-image of $f(a)$. It is not a function. It is not necessary to be 1-1