# Is inverse image defined for a map not surjective?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$.
According to a book [1] I'm reading, the inverse image is defined as following:
For $B \subset Y$, the set $\{p \in X| f(p) \in B\}$ is called the inverse image of $B$ and written as $f^{-1}(B)$.

By this definition, the inverse image is defined even if $f$ is not surjective. More precisely, consider the following statement:
$f^{-1}(B)$ is defined even if $Y \not \subset \{f(x) \in Y| x\in X \}$ --- statement (i).

Is statement (i) is true?

I think it is true. However, I see confusing information: Some web page [2] says explicitly says so, but an answer [3] in Stack Exchange Mathematics seems to be denying.

Let me show my understanding by examples. I think the following descriptions are all correct.

Example 1. Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$, $Y = \{10,20,30\}$, and $f(1)=10$, $f(2)=10$, and $f(3)=20$. Then, $f^{-1}(\{10\}) = \{1,2\}$, $f^{-1}(\{10,20,30\}) = \{1,2,3\}$, $f^{-1}(Y)= X$, and $f^{-1}(\{30\}) =\emptyset$.

Example 2. Let $X = (-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $Y=(-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x \in X$. Then, for $B =(-\frac{1}{100}, \frac{1}{100}) \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(B)=[0,\frac{1}{10})$. (See Addendum 2022-12-04 23:33 UTC below.)

Example 3. The inverse image is defined even if the inverse map does not exist.

This is an elementary question about commonly used terminology.

- [1] Yukio Matsumoto, Basics of Manifold (Tayoutai no Kiso) (University of Tokyo Press, 1988, in Japaese)
- [2] Definitions and examples of image and inverse image of a map illustrated, Landscape of Mathematics (in Japanese) https://mathlandscape.com/map-image/
- [3] A. Inverse image of function
  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1746214/30391

---

Addendum 2022-12-04 23:33 UTC

By the comments from Aphelli and fleablood, I realized that Example 2 above is incorrect. I think the following version is correct.

Example 2c. Let $X = (-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $Y=(-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x \in X$. Then, for $B =(-\frac{1}{100}, \frac{1}{100}) \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(B)=(-\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{10})$.

Comment: If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is *any* map between *sets*, for any subset $B$ of $Y$, we define $f^{-1}(B)$ as the set of $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \in B$. So Examples 1 and 3 are correct, not example 2 (as $f^{-1}(B)=(-1/10,1/10)$).

Comment: About example 2, I don't agree with you. Let $y = -1/20 \in (-1/10, 1/10)$. There's no $x \in X$ such that $f(x) =y$. This contradicts with your definition of $f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: All your examples seem good to me.  And makes sense to me too.  How should the "inverse image" be defined and should every subset have an inverse image?  It  seems to me "the inverse image of $B$ is all the images is all the values mapped to $B$" is a valid on and if there aren't any values mapped to some or even any of them there is no compelling reason to make exceptions.  If $f(x) =x^2$ and I'm asked "what's the inverse image of $(-5,-3)$" I have utterly no qualms answer "The empty set as no reals are mapped to any of those values".

Comment: I don’t understand your point? $x:=-1/20 \in X$ and $f(x)=1/400 \in B$, so $x \in f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Oh... I agree with @Aphelli that 2) is not valid.  You objection doesn't matter that there is no $f(x)=y$.  The issue is that for all $x\in (-\frac 1{10},\frac 1{10})$ then $f(x) \in B$.  And $f(-\frac 1{20}) = \frac 1{400} \in (-1,1)$ so $-\frac 1{20}\in f^{-1}(-\frac 1{100},\frac 1{100})$..... In other words $w\in f^{-1}(B)$ *NOT* if there is an $x$ so that $f(x) =w$.  $w \in f^{-1}(B)$ if there is an $x$ so that $f(w) =x$.

Comment: @Aphelli You are right. Thank you. I was wrong. Thanks to fleablood, too.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being wrong.

Comment: In the other SE thread you linked, the first part of the answer ("Your first question is no") is either wrong or extremely unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is actually a question about functions $f : X \to Y$ between **sets** $X,Y$. It is completely irrelevant whether $X,Y$ carry additional structures like topologies or something else.

It seems to me that you are confused by the use of the symbol $f^{-1}$. In fact, it is used in two different situations.

1. For a bijection $f : X \to Y$ one uses $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ to denote the *inverse function* defined by
   $$f^{-1}(y) = \text{unique element } x \in X \text{ such that } f(x) = y.$$
2. For each function $f : X \to Y$ and each $B \subset Y$ one defines the *inverse image of $B$ under $f$* as
   $$ f^{-1}(B) = \{  \in X \mid f(x) \in B\} .$$
   This assocation can be regarded as a function
   $$f^{-1} : \mathfrak P(Y) \to \mathfrak P(X), $$
   where $\mathfrak P(Z)$ denotes the power set of the set $Z = X, Y$.

Note that if $f$ is a bijection, then for each $y \in Y$ the set $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ contains *exactly one element of $X$* which is denoted by $f^{-1}(y)$. **This is the relationship between 1. and 2.**

Thus all of your examples are correct. Your statement

> (i) $f^{-1}(B)$ is defined even if $Y \not \subset \{f(x) \in Y | x\in X \}$

is also correct, but its formulation is a bit  strange: $Y \not \subset \{f(x) \in Y| x\in X \}$ says that $f$ is not surjective.

The set $f(X) = \{f(x)| x\in X \} \subset Y$ is denoted as the *image of $X$ under $f$*. Clearly $f$ is surjective (which by definition means that for each $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $y = f(x)$) if and only if $Y  = f(X)$. Since $f(X) \subset Y$, the equation $Y  = f(X)$ is equivalent to $Y \subset f(X)$, and the negation  $Y \not\subset f(X)$ occuring in (i) is equivalent to $Y  \ne f(X)$ and equivalent to $f(X) \subsetneqq Y$.

Also note that for each $A \subset X$ one defines the *image of $A$ under $f$* as
$$f(A) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in A \}.$$
This assocation can be regarded as a function
$$f : \mathfrak P(X) \to \mathfrak P(Y). $$
Here you have another example that the same symbol is used for two different situations: We have the function $f : X \to Y$ assigning to elements of $X$ elements of $Y$ ,and we have the function $f : \mathfrak P(X) \to \mathfrak P(Y)$ assigning to subsets of $X$ subsets of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you. All you said make sense. About your last sentence, maybe I could have written $B \not \subset \{f(x) \in Y| x \in X\}$. I translated "$f$ is not surjective" to the symbols because I was not sure if I understood the definition of "surjective" correctly when the similarly elementary-looking term "inverse image" was in doubt.

Comment: @norio See my update. As you say, $f^{-1}(B)$ is **always defined**, but may be empty. This happens if and only if $f(X) \cap B = \emptyset$.